# How to store Bytes/Slice(UInt8) as a string in Crystal?

Tags: redis, crystal-lang

I'm encoding an Object into `Bytes` (ie `Slice(UInt8)`) via MessagePack. How would I store this in a datastore client (eg [Crystal-Redis](https://github.com/stefanwille/crystal-redis)) that only accepts Strings?

Comment: Crystal-Redis appears to not support Redis' byte [string](https://redis.io/topics/data-types#strings) type. This should be a bug report, not a search for workarounds.

Comment: @OlehPrypin You're right. But, the byte string support doesn't seem planned anytime soon in the shard (https://github.com/stefanwille/crystal-redis/issues/47).

Answer (score 1):

If you have no other choice to store the Slice as a String, you can encode it as a String, but at the cost of reduced performance.

There's [Base64 strict_encode/decode](https://crystal-lang.org/api/0.23.1/Base64.html):

```
encoded = An_Object.to_msgpack # Slice(UInt8)
save_to_datastore "my_stuff", Base64.strict_encode(encoded)
from_storage = get_from_datastore "my_stuff"
if from_storage
   My_MsgPack_Mapping.from_msgpack( Base64.decode(from_storage) )
end
```

Or you can use  [Slice#hexstring](http://devdocs.io/crystal/api/0.23.0/slice#hexstring-instance-method)  and  [String#hexbytes](http://devdocs.io/crystal/api/0.23.0/string#hexbytes:Bytes-instance-method):

```
encoded = An_Object.to_msgpack # Slice(UInt8)
save_to_datastore "my_stuff", encoded.hexstring
from_storage = get_from_datastore "my_stuff"
if from_storage && from_storage.hexbytes?
   My_MsgPack_Mapping.from_msgpack( from_storage.hexbytes )
end
```

(Crystal-Redis users have another option: [see this issue](https://github.com/stefanwille/crystal-redis/issues/47).)

Answer (score 1):

Both Crystal and Redis should be able to handle strings with non-valid UTF-8 bytes, so you could just directly create a `String` from the slice and store this to Redis and vice versa.

This is of course not entirely safe: you should make sure to avoid invoking any string methods that expect a valid UTF-8 string.
But apart from that, this direct method should be perfectly fine. Is is faster and more memory-efficient than using a string encoding.

```
redis.set key, String.new(slice)
redis.get(key).to_slice
```

Comment: Please don't do this. It does appear that Redis supports bytestrings, while this particular Crystal Redis wrapper does not. File a bug there instead.

Comment: True, this would be best integrated into a wrapper library. But this should certainly be preferred over some encoding that only costs time and memory.